# CSS/HTML Layout Help

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code...

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="app-actionbar">
        topbar
    </div>
    <div id="app-userinfo">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div id="app-content">
        content
    </div>
</div>

/** Styling **/

#app {
    border:1px solid #666;
}

#app-actionbar {
    color: #333;
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    background: #D9D9DC;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#app-content { 
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 350px;
    width: 725px;
    display: inline;
}

#app-userinfo { 
    color: #333;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    height: 350px;
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
}
```

However, it's not working like I want it to.

I want to add a border around it, but its not working (and its moving the content down).

[image]

Comment: Which part do you want to add the border to?

Comment: You will have to be a bit more clear or supply an image of how you want it to actually look without the SO community guessing what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I can tell what he wants... It's not a mystery. http://jsfiddle.net/P9AQp/

Comment: @Jared, arrr, that layout pretty much looks like his screen shot (of what the problem is)

Comment: @Dan - Yes, I know; it's his exact posted markup/css. It wasn't difficult for me to see the problem when I looked at it. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **clear the floated elements** in your `#app` . Try adding `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;` to `#app`. That will get the border to wrap you entire DIV.

Here's a live **jsfiddle** link of your above snippets with the `overflow:hidden` assigned:
**http://jsfiddle.net/AhZAU/**

The spacing at the top, "(and its moving the content down)", is being created by the `margin-top:10px` on the `#app-actionbar`. Remove the margin and the space will no longer be present: http://jsfiddle.net/AhZAU/1/

Comment: There are two parts to this question: `"I want to add a border around it, but its not working (and its moving the content down)."`

Comment: The border isn't working because the floated elements are not cleared. And it's being pushed down because he has a margin-top:10px assigned to the #app-actionbar DIV.

Comment: @thirtydot, I interpreted the question as in "I want the border to go all the way around but it's not working and instead is creating a margin space at the top". Which I guess is clear, once I've read over it a few times =P Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but his text "content" definitely looks in the wrong place to me, so that's why I think it's that. Let's wait for some feedback from the OP.

Comment: @Dan - I'm pretty sure @thirtydot is right. I had seen it down there but it' didn't register with me, I just thought it was odd. On second thought, I think @thirtydot's right.

Comment: @Jared, @thirtydot is always right =D He's like the Chuck Norris of the web!

Comment: @thirtydot exactly what I thought and answered with a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rga4E/)

Answer (score 2):

The [QuirksMode Way©](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html):

```
#app {
    border:1px solid #666;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CePt6/

From the article:

> If you want to add, say, a border
>   around all floats (ie. a border around
>   the container)...

**NOTE**

As far as the gap at the top, you can eliminate that by removing `margin-top: 10px;` from `#app-actionbar`.

```
#app-actionbar {
    color: #333;
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    background: #D9D9DC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CePt6/2/

**EDIT**

Now, if you mean the content block is moving down, make the width of the `#app` the same width as your `#app-actionbar`:

```
#app {
    border:1px solid #666;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CePt6/3/

Comment: There are two parts to this question: `"I want to add a border around it, but its not working (and its moving the content down)."`

Comment: @thirtydot - Yes, I just remembered the second part. See my last edit. ;)

Comment: I think he means he wants the `content` to the right of the sidebar, not underneath it.

Comment: @thirtydot - Doh! Ok, added that too.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick. [jsfiddle.net demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wPzcX/)

```
#app {
border:1px solid #666;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
width: 900px;
}

#app-actionbar {
color: #333;
width: 900px;
float: left;
height: 45px;
background: #D9D9DC;
}

#app-content { 
float: left;
color: #333;
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 350px;
width: 725px;
display: inline;
}

#app-userinfo { 
color: #333;
background:#F2F2F2;
height: 350px;
width: 175px;
float: left;
clear: left;
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code to your answer. As the moment, I have no way to see what code renders like without expending effort, so I'm not as likely to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for giggles, tried that but with some layout changes. Check if it helps. ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rga4E/))

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="app-actionbar">
        topbar
    </div>
    <div id="app-userinfo">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div id="app-content">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#app {
    border:1px solid #666;
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
}

#app-actionbar {
    color: #333;
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    height: 45px;
    background: #D9D9DC;
    margin-top:0px; 
}

#app-content { 
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    background: red;
    height: 350px;
    width: 725px;
    display: inline; 

    left:200px;
    top:75px;
}

#app-userinfo { 
    color: #333;
    background:#F2F2F2;
    height: 350px;
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
    top:65px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

Add the following lines to your #app div like this:

```
width:900px;
min-height: 300px;
overflow:auto;
```

The above is meant to auto-expand the outer div as the inner contents increase in length.

This however will be a restriction on older versions of IE since they did not have the min-height property.